# Adding tags should have a min. cap of 5k+

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Currently we have a min. of 300 rep points, which is imo too low. In nearly every Q someone starts getting "*creative*" and adds a tag.

Examples: [headlineslider](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headlineslider), [flickr-slideshow-plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flickr-slideshow-plugin), etc.

This is *annoying*, as it makes it close to impossible to search the tags if I need something.

---

**EDIT:**

Currently we got ~1.000 tags - which means that we got 10 Qs per tag. When you sort tags per popularity, then we got around 1/5th (200+) tags with only 1 Q tagged. The next is ~100 tags (1/10th) having two Qs attached.

Honsetly: Tags like [idea](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idea), [gigya](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gigya) or [athalupa](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/athalupa) ... ? Not to forget: [func](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/func) & [plug](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plug)

---

**EDIT 2:**

Sounds like there's no possibility to actually *delete* tags. SO/SE-Team: This one's really missing. Else tags would clutter the page and be unuseable in about ... already now.

Comment: it's possible but might be a bit early in the site's lifecycle for that

Comment: Thanks for reading & commenting. Pls take a look at the tags list and how many tags just got 1-some few Qs. This mostly comes from users who don't have enough experience.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood See edit/update of Q.

Answer (score 4):

By my count based on latest available data explorer snapshot **less than 150 questions** were asked by users with reputation over 5k.

With such required reputation virtually no tags will be created at all... other than going around and explicitly creating them.

Currently we have more than enough issues to occupy high rep users without that (thousand+ questions without answers for example).

Comment: 5k+ is just a number. Idea about a lower limit? Maybe 2k+? Imo it's not fixed, just a suggestion. But 300 is too low...

Comment: @kaiser the distribution of new question is almost all by accounts with lower rep. It is less troublesome to have high rep users manage cleanup, than make them handle creation for all tags.

Comment: See edit... 300 still is too low. What would you personally set as limit?

Comment: "... virtually no tags will be created at all..." -- I agree that 5000 is too high, but I do look at the tags on questions and edit them, so tags would still be created if needed (which I expect would be rarely).

Answer (score 4):

Please note that single-instance tags (that is, tags which only exist on a *single* question) are automatically culled after 6 months.

[Should We Zap The Low-Occurrence Tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418)

It really is far too early in the lifecycle of the site for this to be an issue. I'd be more worried about finding proper tag synonyms and merges for the tags that are in active use.

Comment: Please see update and new answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think 5k is too much. But 1k should be a usable limit. Our [new tags](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) get messy way too fast. From today:

- saving
- plugin-solr-for-wordpress
- the-title
- limit
- formating [!]

… and so on. These tags are then available by autocomplete, they are used more than once and we have to clean up the mess manually.

Oh, and a link to the new tags on the review page would be useful. Otherwise we forget to take a look regularly.

Now I see there is a **bug**, which may cause some of our problems with low quality tags. The [inventor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/10099/alxvallejo?tab=reputation) of the *plugin-solr-for-wordpress* tag has 46 points of reputation. The current limit just doesn’t work.

Comment: _ahem_ [inventor of `plugin-solr-for-wordpress`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/39376/revisions) has something over of twenty six thousands points of reputation. :) And that is a plugin in repository that is literally called that, what's the issue?

Comment: @Rarst Oh, I missed that. :) Do we really need a separate tag for each plugin? Wouldn’t `search-plugin` be more useful?

Comment: I like tags for individual plugins because then developers can subscribe to RSS of their plugins. Obviously some plugins are too obscure and this might or might not be the case.

Comment: @Rarst That would be my opinion too. If we got a tag for every single plugin, then we'd have thousands of tags for only that (not including aliases). I'm absolutely against that.

Comment: @kaiser but there isn't question about every single plugin. And plugins tend to get more than one question about them (user base by usage complexity). I would take organized tags of specific format over everyone tagging it by random unspecific tags (exactly what this thread is about).

Comment: Okay, let’s put the plugin tags aside. `limit`, `saving` or `formating` should never happen. Agreed?

Comment: @toscho Aside from plugins: Agree. 101%

Answer (score 2):

Would it fit your needs to limit new users to a limited number of tags, say your most common, or a hard-coded set of general categories?

If a tag is also the name of a forum, could that signal a warning of some sort?

I'm very new here.  I posted my first question on Stack Overflow, without realizing that I should be doing it at wordpress.stackexchange.com.  I tagged it wordpress.  If that tag had generated a warning notice, I would have gone to wordpress.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Point is not the tagging itself. It's the minimum reputation that's needed to _create tags_. It's such low that every one starts getting creative on creating tags without really knowing the system and even less what it's about with tags.